# How to deploy jupyter notebook application in AWS ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I have created an application (calculator)using Jupyter notebook on my local machine.

I want this calculator to be public when I type in the URL after deploying in Aws ec2

I want to know is there a way to deploy my application in AWS ec2 instance(ubuntu) to make my application public.

Is there a step by step guide to deploy my application?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "make my application public"? Do you want people to access your Jupyter notebook? Does it have authentication? Are you okay if hundreds of people try to access it? Is there any information in there that you potentially want to keep private? Might these users be able to modify the notebook and thereby ruin the experience for future users? Giving public access to the Jupyter interface is not something normally done. Have you successfully deployed it on the EC2 instance yet (even if it isn't public)?

Comment: no i Have not done deploying in ec2 i want to know how to do it even in private. is there are step by step procedure to do so? kindly help on this regard @JohnRotenstein